# CSS into jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to replace the following css with jQuery?

```
input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" >
  <span class="slider"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: No it's not, javascript has no access to pseudoelements like `:before`

Comment: If you want to edit the CSS of a pseudo-element with JS, the best option is the have CSS assigned to classes which you can add to the base element `.slider` with JS. If you need more control than that, then it's not really plausible with a `:before`

Comment: Why you want to use JQuery instead of CSS?